# Getting NullPointerException when called remote soap service (javax.xml.ws)

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I try to get the client instance:

```
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
Service remoteSoapService = Service.create(new URL("http://myurl?wsdl"), new QName("http://myNamespaceURI", "myLocalPart"));
```

When this line is executed I get an exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>
> org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.(WSDLServiceFactory.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:218)
>     at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initialize(ServiceImpl.java:161)
>     at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.(ServiceImpl.java:129)    at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:82)
>     at javax.xml.ws.Service.(Service.java:77)     at
>
> javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:707)

But it occurs only when program is run as a jar: "java -jar programName.jar".
If I launch my application from intellijIdea the exception aren't thrown and all work correctly.

What is the difference between running program as a jar and from intellijIdea? What could be the probmlem with jar and how to fix it?

Comment: Could you provide code (GitHub, etc ..)?

Most probably, your classpath is different. If you run from idea jdk could be used, but your java -jar could use only jre. For more details I need see your project,sry

Comment: I agree with the last comment, when run from the command line it's likely not finding some required jar files

Comment: That's right. I found the problem - it was a libraries version conflict. I remove "camel-cxf" and added "jsr311-api". And application has worked correctly. I couldn't provide code, but thanks for answers.